# Hourly spikes in php grpc call

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am running a Php application (client) that communicates with rust application (server) via Grpc/Protobuf. I am seeing consistent hourly spikes for these calls.

Usually, the grpc call will be around 2-4 ms. But the hourly spike ranges from 30 ms to 1.5 seconds.

I wanted to know what is the reason for this spike and any possible way to avoid these spikes.

**protobuf version -** 3.15.5

**grpc version -** 1.36.0

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. There was an hourly flow in the server that was causing the spikes.